# how to switch back to HEAD

Tags: git

In order to test a commit, I did:

```
git checkout 1234
```

after the test, I want to go back to HEAD, but I can only go back to the master by

```
git checkout master

$ git status
On branch master
```

What command I can go back to HEAD?

Comment: `HEAD` isn't a specific place - it just means "tip of the current branch"  (or "tip of a specified branch"). When you do `git checkout master` it will checkout to the `HEAD` of `master`. You cannot `checkout` to different branches or commit-refs in a way that preserves any uncommitted changes - you need to `git stash` for that.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong terminology - so in your own words please tell us what you think "HEAD" is? What difference do you observe between what you think is `HEAD` and `git checkout master`?

Comment: In another git repo, when executed 'git status', I can see  'HEAD detached at xxxxx', I don't want to see 'On branch master ..... '

Comment: Please read [this of the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell)

Comment: Why don't you want to see "On branch master" - what's wrong with your `master` branch, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git has, in this case, two modes:

- "on a branch": the special name `HEAD`, in all uppercase like this,<sup>1</sup> contains the name of a branch.
- "detached HEAD": the special name `HEAD` contains the raw hash ID of a commit.

Given that the second mode is called *detached* HEAD mode, I like to call the first mode *attached HEAD* mode.

While you can use Git in the second mode as much as you like, the way most people prefer to use Git is in the first mode, because it's usually more useful.  The detached HEAD mode exists for two primary reasons:

- to let you view any particularly interesting commit, by running `git checkout hash-id` or `git checkout tag-name` for instance; or
- to handle an in-progress `git rebase` that requires human assistance.

To force detached mode when using a branch name, you can (as you noted at one point) use `git checkout --detach name`—but unless you're implementing a new Git command, or something along these lines, that's not a normal thing to do.

The reason we normally use attached HEAD mode is that when you make a new commit in this mode, Git will remember its hash ID for you automatically.  Commits, in Git, are in the end always found by their hash IDs.  Each new commit you make acquires a new, unique hash ID—one that has never been used for any other commit before, and will never be used for any other commit ever again either.  If you wish to revisit this commit again later, you must save this hash ID somewhere.

Every Git commit saves some earlier-commit hash IDs.  Most commits save exactly one such ID, which Git calls the *parent* of the commit.  This hash ID is the commit you extracted earlier.

Remember that each commit holds a snapshot of all your files, but in a special read-only, Git-only, compressed form, with file de-duplication so that repeatly committing the same file doesn't actually take any extra space.  These committed files can never be changed, so they're great for archival, but nothing except Git can *read* them and they are therefore useless for getting any new work done.  Git has to copy them out to a work area in order for you to even *see* the files.

That's what `git checkout` does: you give it a name (which Git turns into a hash ID) or a hash ID, and Git extracts that frozen commit into a useful form.  Now you can see and work with the commit.  If you then make a *new* commit, the *new* commit's parent hash ID will be the hash ID Git used to extract the *current* commit.  Then, having made the new commit, Git makes that new commit *become* the current commit.

That is how branches grow: you check out a branch name like `master`, work on the files in your work-tree, tell Git to copy any updates back to make them ready for commit (`git add`), and use `git commit` to make the new snapshot / commit.  This commit then remembers which commit the branch name *used* to say, and Git updates the branch name to say *this new commit is the last one*.

Hence, by definition, each branch name *is* the last commit for that branch.  That commit remembers its (historical) parent, which lets you or Git find its hash ID if you wish to extract it.  If you do, you enter the detached HEAD mode, with the parent as the current commit.  That commit remembers *its* parent, which lets you or Git find the hash ID, so that you can check out *that* commit, and so on.

In the end, what this really means is that you normally don't bother to tell Git: *use attached HEAD mode* or *use detached HEAD mode*.  You just pick a branch name if you want the *latest* commit *and* the ability to add new commits here, or a raw hash ID (or a tag name, or some other name) if you don't want the latest commit and aren't concerned about the ability to add new commits.

The drawback to detached HEAD mode is that if you *do* add new commits, the only *name* that can find them is `HEAD`.  As soon as you pick some other commit, or some branch name, Git loses the ability to *find* the new commits you made.  So it's rare to want to do *new* work in detached HEAD mode.  It's not that you can't—and commands like `git rebase` put this mode to good effect–but it's *rare* to want it.

(You never explained *why* you wanted it, but the above contains the answer to how to get it: just pick a commit by historical name, or use `--detach` if using a branch name.  Just remember not to *stay* in this mode if you want to get new work done.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Sometimes you can use `head`, in lowercase, and it works—or at least seems to work.  This is a bad habit to get into though, because while it works OK by default on MacOS and Windows, it doesn't work at all by default on Linux.  Moreover, if you start using `git worktree add`, it stops working correctly even on MacOS and Linux.

The real reason it works—or doesn't, when it doesn't—is that Git stores data for the special name `HEAD` in a *file* named `.git/HEAD`, or a file of some other name such as `.git/worktrees/foo/HEAD`.  If you use the lowercase `head`, Git will, pretty early on, try to read the file `.git/head`.  On a case-insensitive file system, this winds up reading the file `.git/HEAD`, which gets that file's data and allows Git to proceed.  With an added work-tree, this is the *wrong* `HEAD`, so Git proceeds to use the *wrong commit*.

If you don't like typing out all-caps `HEAD`, consider using its single-character synonym `@`.